# Swift - Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: swift, macos

I have a swift framework in which i am doing some calculations in c files. I have set the C file header target as public, but If I use this framework in any App, the c file itself is exposed to the App which I dont want to. Is there any solution or workaround for this?

some one please help..